# Wake up a thread spawned using ScheduledExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading, scheduledexecutorservice

I am using ScheduledExecutorService to spawn a thread as below:

```
    private ScheduledExecutorService ses = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    private ScheduledFuture<?> scheduledFuture = ses.scheduleWithFixedDelay(() -> { cleanup(); }, 0L, 5L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

There is a sleep of 5 seconds in between executions of the cleanup function.

In certain conditions, is there a provision to wake this thread up to start running the cleanup instead of waiting for the 5 seconds to trigger it?

Example: at time T1 -> cleanup is called, at T1+2s -> i want to wake up the thread to do the cleanup explicity

Comment: Well, you can just schedule the cleanup task for immediate execution in this case (using [schedule](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#schedule(java.lang.Runnable,long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) with a delay of 0). No need to explicitly wake anything up.

Comment: Well, i need to do the cleanup every 5 seconds. But in between, there might be a need to run the cleanup between lets say 10th second and 15th second, what is the way to wake up the thread explicitly?

Answer (score 2):

> i want to wake up the thread to do the cleanup explicity.

Why not simply *call* `cleanup()` from whatever other thread sees the need?

```
void someTerriblyImportantFunction(...) {
    ...
    if (thisPlaceNeedsToBeCleanedUp_Like_NOW()) {
        cleanup();
    }
    ...
}
```

> I can do that, but i wanted the thread to always run cleanup instead.

First of all, you can not depend on the thread pool to always use the same thread when it executes your cleanup task. You created the pool by calling `Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1)`, but the `1` argument only specifies the *minimum* number of threads in the pool.  In a program that uses the same thread pool for more than one thing, the pool is free to create and destroy worker threads as needed, so long as it always keeps one thread ready.

Secondly, and this is just my personal opinion, it's good practice to design your multi-threaded program in such a way that, whenever some task needs to be performed, it should not matter which thread performs it. In this case, I would design `cleanup()` so that it can be safely called at any time, from any thread.

---

P.S., Also note what @Hulk said in a comment: If `cleanup()` takes more time than the caller is willing to wait for, then another option would be to submit a "one-shot" task to be scheduled as soon as possible by the same thread pool.

```
void someTerriblyImportantFunction(...) {
    ...
    if (thisPlaceNeedsToBeCleanedUp_RealSoon()) {
        ses.schedule(() -> { cleanup(); }, 1L, TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS);
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: I can do that, but i wanted the thread to always run cleanup instead.